# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging supported in China?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I seen a lot of post saying China banned majority of google's services, and there are also posts that say GCM does not work in China. Since Firebase is owned by Google, does FCM work in China (more specifically, FCM for Android)?

Does Firebase/Google has a list of countries that don't support its services?

Comment: https://www.greatfirewallofchina.org

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/2XwWpbHoONs) is an old thread, but I believe it's still valid.

Comment: @PeterHaddad something weird happens there. "google.com" is blocked, but "firebase.google.com" succeeds

Comment: GCM/FCM are definitely blocked in China. To send notifications in China, check out Pushy (https://pushy.me/) which works worldwide using the lightweight MQTT protocol and is completely independent of GCM/FCM. It's also easy to migrate from FCM. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.